# Concatenate strings using with_items and assign to a variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I need to save two 2 IPs to a variable in a vars_file when launching ec2_instances, which are used later during deployment.

This is how I am saving a single server ip:

```
- name: Save server public IP to vars file
  lineinfile: line="server_public_ip{{':'}} {{ item.public_ip }}"
              dest="{{ansible_env.HOME}}/dynamic_ips_{{ec2_environment}}"
  with_items: server.instances  #server is registered in previous task
```

The output I have in dynamic_ips file is **`server_public_ip: xxx.xxx.xx.x`**

Now I have 2 servers launched and registered as servers.

I need to save this as **`server_public_ips: xxx.xx.x.xx , xxx.x.xx.x`**

I tried to declare an empty string and append ips to it, something like this, but I am getting errors.

```
set_fact:
   ips: ""
set_fact:
   ips: " {{ ips }} + {{ item.public_ip}} "
with_items: servers.instances  #servers is registered in previous task
lineinfile: line="server_public_ips{{':'}} {{ ips }}"
            dest="{{ansible_env.HOME}}/dynamic_ips_{{ec2_environment}}"
```

I think it can be done using lineinfile insertafter and regex.

Finally, I need this to do this in a different server,

```
- name: Restrict access to outside world
  command: iptables INPUT {{ item }} ACCEPT
  with_items: {{ server_public_ips }}.split(,) #grant access for each ip 
  command: iptables INPUT DROP
```

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors in this code... And why at the first place do you need to store *dynamic* ips in static file? You should query them at runtime.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov How can I query for IP's at run time. I only have the ec2 instance names. Is it possible to get the IPs using instance name at runtime? Also I have two instances with same name. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set_fact:
   ips: " {{servers.instances | join(',') }} "
```

should actually work when servers.instances is a list.

Comment: Is servers.instances a list? servers is json .

Comment: Well, then use the from_json method which converts the json to a dict