# is this method used for string concatenation of variables using a with_items loop correct?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2, string-concatenation

input file

```
[centos@linux1 tmp]$ cat data.txt
a car has 4 wheels
a bike has 2 wheels
```

output file

```
[centos@linux1 tmp]$ cat final_list

vehicle: car blah blah
vehicle: bike blah blah
```

playbook

```
[centos@linux1 tmp]$ cat test.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: check vehicle types
     shell: "cat /tmp/data.txt | grep 'car\\|bike' | awk '{print $2}'"
     register: vehicle_list

   - name : create a empty string variable
     set_fact:
      var1: ''

   - name: concate strings
     set_fact:
      var1: "{{var1}}\nvehicle: {{item}} blah blah"
     with_items: "{{vehicle_list.stdout_lines}}"

   - name: output to file
     shell: echo "{{var1}}" >> /tmp/final_list
```

i am able to get desired results, but i think the code is unreadable and difficult for others to debug

Question : is the method used to concatenate variables in task `- name: concate strings` in a with_items loop correct 
OR
are there cleaner ways to do it ?

i expected to use join method as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42905081/5889962) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050325/5889962)
but i was not able to get them to work

EDIT: how to achieve string concatenation in a with items loop, using conventional methods as described in other answers ?

1) python string concatenation

```
var1=var1+"vehicle: {{item}} blah blah\n"
```

2)join filters

```
var1: "{{vehicle: {{item}} blah blah | join('\n') }}"
```

3)join method

```
var1: "{{ '\n'.join((vehicle: {{item}} blah blah)) }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several improvements you can make here.  First, this command doesn't need `cat` or `grep`:

```
- name: check vehicle types
  shell: "cat /tmp/data.txt | grep 'car\\|bike' | awk '{print $2}'"
  register: vehicle_list
```

You can just write:

```
- name: check vehicle types
  command: "awk '/car|bike/ {print $2}' /tmp/data.txt"
  register: vehicle_list
```

Next, you don't need that first `set_fact` statement, because you can take advantage of the `default` filter to provide a value for `var1` if it is not yet defined:

```
- name: concatenate strings
  set_fact:
    var1: "{{var1|default('')}}vehicle: {{item}} blah blah\n"
  with_items: "{{vehicle_list.stdout_lines}}"
```

Notice that I've also relocated the `\n` so that the resulting file doesn't start with a blank line.

Finally, you're using a `shell` task to append your data to a file. If you don't *actually* need to append, you can just use Ansible's `copy` module to create your output file:

```
- name: output to file
  copy:
    content: "{{ var1 }}"
    dest: /tmp/final_list
```

If you do need to append the data, rather than overwriting the file, then you current solution is okay, although I would probably write it like this:

```
- name: output to file
  shell: "cat >> /tmp/final_list"
  args:
    stdin: "{{ var1 }}"
```

---

The above *is* a "usual method", but you certainly have alternatives. If you were to build up a list of lines, like this:

```
- name: create list
  set_fact:
    var1: "{{var1|default([]) + ['vehicle: %s blah blah' % (item)] }}"
  with_items: "{{vehicle_list.stdout_lines}}"
```

Then you can use the `join` filter to produce your output:

```
- name: output to file
  copy:
    content: "{{ var1|join('\n') }}"
    dest: /tmp/final_list
```

Or do the same thing using the string `.join` method:

```
- name: output to file
  copy:
    content: "{{ '\n'.join(var1) }}"
    dest: /tmp/final_list
```

Comment: appreciate the effort, my initial question was how to concatenate using usual methods like string concatenation or join method ? edited the question